# Derivation of \$Z_{och}\$ & \$ Z_{sch} \$ for a symmetrical lattice two port network

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks

I am trying to derive the open circuit impedance of half circuit [i.e \$Z_{och}\$ ] and short circuit impedance of half circuit [i.e \$Z_{sch}\$ ] of symmetric lattice two port network (which is shown below in the diagram) is given as:
$$Z_{och}= Z_2$$
$$Z_{sch}= Z_1$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Uifs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**My Approach**:
In order to derive \$ Z_{och} \$ & \$  Z_{sch} \$ , we must divide the given two port network into two equal parts as stated by **Bartlett's Bisection Theorem**

so,for \$ Z_{sch} \$ :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu6Na9.png)</sup>

where  **red**  line representing the shorted line to find short circuit half circuit impedance

Now taking \$ 11'\$ port
we get: $$Z_{sch}= \frac{Z_1}{2} + \frac{Z_1}{2}=Z_1$$
Thus,we derived for \$ Z_{sch} \$

Similarly,for \$ Z_{och} \$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc1inh.png)</sup>
Now taking \$ 11'\$ port
we get, \$ Z_{och}= \infty \quad [ \because \$ we don't get any closed path from 1 to 1']

,but we know \$ Z_{och} = Z_2\$ ; so did i missed any concept? , please help anyone...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Don't forget to multiply the normalized results by 50 Ohm for S11.

Comment: What will i do after finding \$S_{11} \$ ? I need to find \$Z_{och} \$ not \$S_{11} \$ !